# data.table rolling average timestamp window

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I have the following data.table (excerpt only):

```
               posix_dt sentiment score
 1: 2019-11-02 08:45:06    0.0000     2
 2: 2019-11-02 08:45:07    0.0000     5
 3: 2019-11-02 08:45:08    0.0201     4
 4: 2019-11-02 08:45:14    0.2732     7
 5: 2019-11-02 08:45:25    0.0000     3
 6: 2019-11-02 08:45:35    0.3182    16
 7: 2019-11-02 08:45:48    0.0000     3
 8: 2019-11-02 08:45:53   -0.3582     6
 9: 2019-11-02 08:46:00    0.4003     6
10: 2019-11-02 08:46:00    0.0000     7
11: 2019-11-02 08:46:04    0.0000     4
12: 2019-11-02 08:46:07    0.0000     2
13: 2019-11-02 08:46:16    0.4939     0
14: 2019-11-02 08:46:19    0.0000     2
15: 2019-11-02 08:46:32   -0.5267     2
16: 2019-11-02 08:46:49    0.2960     0
17: 2019-11-02 08:47:05    0.9753     7
18: 2019-11-02 08:47:05    0.0000     9
19: 2019-11-02 08:47:07    0.0000     3
20: 2019-11-02 08:47:10   -0.2960     9
```

And I would like to calculate a moving average of the score/sentiment columns over a 2 minute window. As you can see there is no pattern to the rate of data per 2 minutes (i.e. I can't just have a window of `n` rows that will always be 2 mins).

In the Python Pandas library [there is a function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) which simply takes a time interval and can do this for you.

I am aware of the `zoo` package and its rolling mean functions but as far as I can tell it requires a fixed/predetermined window size?

For reference my full data is ~12000 rows and covers about 3 hours.

Comment: For evenly spaced time series there is already fast rolling mean in data.table, see `?froll`. For unevenly spaced time series you can try [uts](https://github.com/andreas50/uts) package. There is a FR to support that in data.table, please upvote [data.table#3241](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3241).

Comment: Interesting, `uts` does look like it covers my case, I’m not sure I fully follow that entire FR but the mention of the pandas function seems like it’s what I’d need! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option non-equi join in `data.table`:

```
DT[, posix_dt := as.POSIXct(posix_dt, format="%Y-%m-%d %T")]
DT[, c("start", "end") := .(posix_dt - 2*60, posix_dt)]
DT[, c("rm_sentiment", "rm_score") := 
    .SD[.SD, on=.(posix_dt>=start, posix_dt<=end), 
        by=.EACHI, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols=c("sentiment", "score")][,
            (1L:2L) := NULL]
]
```

output:

```
               posix_dt sentiment score               start                 end rm_sentiment rm_score
 1: 2019-11-02 08:45:06    0.0000     2 2019-11-02 08:43:06 2019-11-02 08:45:06   0.00000000 2.000000
 2: 2019-11-02 08:45:07    0.0000     5 2019-11-02 08:43:07 2019-11-02 08:45:07   0.00000000 3.500000
 3: 2019-11-02 08:45:08    0.0201     4 2019-11-02 08:43:08 2019-11-02 08:45:08   0.00670000 3.666667
 4: 2019-11-02 08:45:14    0.2732     7 2019-11-02 08:43:14 2019-11-02 08:45:14   0.07332500 4.500000
 5: 2019-11-02 08:45:25    0.0000     3 2019-11-02 08:43:25 2019-11-02 08:45:25   0.05866000 4.200000
 6: 2019-11-02 08:45:35    0.3182    16 2019-11-02 08:43:35 2019-11-02 08:45:35   0.10191667 6.166667
 7: 2019-11-02 08:45:48    0.0000     3 2019-11-02 08:43:48 2019-11-02 08:45:48   0.08735714 5.714286
 8: 2019-11-02 08:45:53   -0.3582     6 2019-11-02 08:43:53 2019-11-02 08:45:53   0.03166250 5.750000
 9: 2019-11-02 08:46:00    0.4003     6 2019-11-02 08:44:00 2019-11-02 08:46:00   0.06536000 5.900000
10: 2019-11-02 08:46:00    0.0000     7 2019-11-02 08:44:00 2019-11-02 08:46:00   0.06536000 5.900000
11: 2019-11-02 08:46:04    0.0000     4 2019-11-02 08:44:04 2019-11-02 08:46:04   0.05941818 5.727273
12: 2019-11-02 08:46:07    0.0000     2 2019-11-02 08:44:07 2019-11-02 08:46:07   0.05446667 5.416667
13: 2019-11-02 08:46:16    0.4939     0 2019-11-02 08:44:16 2019-11-02 08:46:16   0.08826923 5.000000
14: 2019-11-02 08:46:19    0.0000     2 2019-11-02 08:44:19 2019-11-02 08:46:19   0.08196429 4.785714
15: 2019-11-02 08:46:32   -0.5267     2 2019-11-02 08:44:32 2019-11-02 08:46:32   0.04138667 4.600000
16: 2019-11-02 08:46:49    0.2960     0 2019-11-02 08:44:49 2019-11-02 08:46:49   0.05730000 4.312500
17: 2019-11-02 08:47:05    0.9753     7 2019-11-02 08:45:05 2019-11-02 08:47:05   0.10511667 4.722222
18: 2019-11-02 08:47:05    0.0000     9 2019-11-02 08:45:05 2019-11-02 08:47:05   0.10511667 4.722222
19: 2019-11-02 08:47:07    0.0000     3 2019-11-02 08:45:07 2019-11-02 08:47:07   0.10511667 4.777778
20: 2019-11-02 08:47:10   -0.2960     9 2019-11-02 08:45:10 2019-11-02 08:47:10   0.09270588 5.058824
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("posix_dt,sentiment,score
2019-11-02 08:45:06,    0.0000    , 2
2019-11-02 08:45:07,    0.0000    , 5
2019-11-02 08:45:08,    0.0201    , 4
2019-11-02 08:45:14,    0.2732    , 7
2019-11-02 08:45:25,    0.0000    , 3
2019-11-02 08:45:35,    0.3182   , 16
2019-11-02 08:45:48,    0.0000    , 3
2019-11-02 08:45:53,   -0.3582    , 6
2019-11-02 08:46:00,    0.4003    , 6
2019-11-02 08:46:00,    0.0000    , 7
2019-11-02 08:46:04,    0.0000    , 4
2019-11-02 08:46:07,    0.0000    , 2
2019-11-02 08:46:16,    0.4939    , 0
2019-11-02 08:46:19,    0.0000    , 2
2019-11-02 08:46:32,   -0.5267    , 2
2019-11-02 08:46:49,    0.2960    , 0
2019-11-02 08:47:05,    0.9753    , 7
2019-11-02 08:47:05,    0.0000    , 9
2019-11-02 08:47:07,    0.0000    , 3
2019-11-02 08:47:10,   -0.2960     ,9")
```

---

Another approach using rolling join which should be faster:

```
#because there are duplicate of posix_dt, 
#thats why there is a need to aggregate first to make posix_dt unique
twomins <- 2L * 60L
aggDT <- DT[, c(.(N=.N), lapply(.SD, sum)), .(posix_dt), .SDcols=cols]

#calculate cumulative sums for calculating means later
cols <- c("N", "sentiment", "score")
aggDT[, c("start", paste0("cs_", cols)) :=
    c(.(posix_dt - twomins), lapply(.SD, cumsum)), .SDcols=cols]

#performing rolling join to find first timing that is >= time 2 minutes ago
#for current row
newcols <- c("rm_sentiment", "rm_score")
aggDT[, (newcols) := aggDT[aggDT, on=.(posix_dt=start), roll=-twomins,
    .((i.cs_sentiment - x.cs_sentiment + x.sentiment) / (i.cs_N - x.cs_N + x.N),
        (i.cs_score - x.cs_score + x.score) / (i.cs_N - x.cs_N + x.N))]
]

#lookup mean values into original DT using update join
DT[aggDT, on=.(posix_dt), paste0(newcols,"2") := mget(paste0("i.", newcols))]
DT
```

output:

```
               posix_dt sentiment score               start                 end rm_sentiment rm_score rm_sentiment2 rm_score2
 1: 2019-11-02 08:45:06    0.0000     2 2019-11-02 08:43:06 2019-11-02 08:45:06   0.00000000 2.000000    0.00000000  2.000000
 2: 2019-11-02 08:45:07    0.0000     5 2019-11-02 08:43:07 2019-11-02 08:45:07   0.00000000 3.500000    0.00000000  3.500000
 3: 2019-11-02 08:45:08    0.0201     4 2019-11-02 08:43:08 2019-11-02 08:45:08   0.00670000 3.666667    0.00670000  3.666667
 4: 2019-11-02 08:45:14    0.2732     7 2019-11-02 08:43:14 2019-11-02 08:45:14   0.07332500 4.500000    0.07332500  4.500000
 5: 2019-11-02 08:45:25    0.0000     3 2019-11-02 08:43:25 2019-11-02 08:45:25   0.05866000 4.200000    0.05866000  4.200000
 6: 2019-11-02 08:45:35    0.3182    16 2019-11-02 08:43:35 2019-11-02 08:45:35   0.10191667 6.166667    0.10191667  6.166667
 7: 2019-11-02 08:45:48    0.0000     3 2019-11-02 08:43:48 2019-11-02 08:45:48   0.08735714 5.714286    0.08735714  5.714286
 8: 2019-11-02 08:45:53   -0.3582     6 2019-11-02 08:43:53 2019-11-02 08:45:53   0.03166250 5.750000    0.03166250  5.750000
 9: 2019-11-02 08:46:00    0.4003     6 2019-11-02 08:44:00 2019-11-02 08:46:00   0.06536000 5.900000    0.06536000  5.900000
10: 2019-11-02 08:46:00    0.0000     7 2019-11-02 08:44:00 2019-11-02 08:46:00   0.06536000 5.900000    0.06536000  5.900000
11: 2019-11-02 08:46:04    0.0000     4 2019-11-02 08:44:04 2019-11-02 08:46:04   0.05941818 5.727273    0.05941818  5.727273
12: 2019-11-02 08:46:07    0.0000     2 2019-11-02 08:44:07 2019-11-02 08:46:07   0.05446667 5.416667    0.05446667  5.416667
13: 2019-11-02 08:46:16    0.4939     0 2019-11-02 08:44:16 2019-11-02 08:46:16   0.08826923 5.000000    0.08826923  5.000000
14: 2019-11-02 08:46:19    0.0000     2 2019-11-02 08:44:19 2019-11-02 08:46:19   0.08196429 4.785714    0.08196429  4.785714
15: 2019-11-02 08:46:32   -0.5267     2 2019-11-02 08:44:32 2019-11-02 08:46:32   0.04138667 4.600000    0.04138667  4.600000
16: 2019-11-02 08:46:49    0.2960     0 2019-11-02 08:44:49 2019-11-02 08:46:49   0.05730000 4.312500    0.05730000  4.312500
17: 2019-11-02 08:47:05    0.9753     7 2019-11-02 08:45:05 2019-11-02 08:47:05   0.10511667 4.722222    0.10511667  4.722222
18: 2019-11-02 08:47:05    0.0000     9 2019-11-02 08:45:05 2019-11-02 08:47:05   0.10511667 4.722222    0.10511667  4.722222
19: 2019-11-02 08:47:07    0.0000     3 2019-11-02 08:45:07 2019-11-02 08:47:07   0.10511667 4.777778    0.10511667  4.777778
20: 2019-11-02 08:47:10   -0.2960     9 2019-11-02 08:45:10 2019-11-02 08:47:10   0.09270588 5.058824    0.09270588  5.058824
```

Comment: I think this is the proper way. Still interested if someone can make my solution more efficient.

Comment: This feels like the "`data.table` way". Could you just clear up what the last part (`1L:2L := NULL`) is for? Also I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with the `end`/`start` columns as temporary intermediates?

Comment: The NULL part removes the first 2 columns used in the join. Just nice there is a feature request for not including these joined columns as output and also a feature request for the temp intermediates like inside the on argument.

Comment: @PyPingu i added another approach which should be faster.

Comment: Wow thanks, there’s quite a bit going on there. I’d say I’m comfortable with most `data.table` basics, but I only use R occasionally and I’m never quite sure on what `.I` does? I’ll step through it when I get the chance but any further explanation of the method would be really appreciated

Comment: .I is a vector of row numbers of the data.table. You can just use the first one. The 2nd one was more of a experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something quick and very inefficient but seems to work:

```
DT[, obs_back := vapply(seq_along(posix_dt), function(i) sum(as.integer(posix_dt[i] - posix_dt[seq_len(i-1)]) < 120) + 1L, integer(1))]
DT[, sentiment_2minmean := diag(as.matrix(DT[, frollmean(sentiment, obs_back)]))]
DT[, score_2minmean := diag(as.matrix(DT[, frollmean(score, obs_back)]))]
```

Reproducible example (please provide it yourself next time):

```
DT <- fread("
 posix_dt, sentiment, score
 2019-11-02 08:45:06,0.0000,2
 2019-11-02 08:45:07,0.0000,5
 2019-11-02 08:45:08,0.0201,4
 2019-11-02 08:45:14,0.2732,7
 2019-11-02 08:45:25,0.0000,3
 2019-11-02 08:45:35,0.3182,16
 2019-11-02 08:45:48,0.0000,3
 2019-11-02 08:45:53,-0.3582,6
 2019-11-02 08:46:00,0.4003,6
 2019-11-02 08:46:00,0.0000,7
 2019-11-02 08:46:04,0.0000,4
 2019-11-02 08:46:07,0.0000,2
 2019-11-02 08:46:16,0.4939,0
 2019-11-02 08:46:19,0.0000,2
 2019-11-02 08:46:32,-0.5267,2
 2019-11-02 08:46:49,0.2960,0
 2019-11-02 08:47:05,0.9753,7
 2019-11-02 08:47:05,0.0000,9
 2019-11-02 08:47:07,0.0000,3
 2019-11-02 08:47:10,-0.2960,9")
DT[, posix_dt := as.POSIXct(posix_dt)]
```

Comment: i think for your first line, you can use a rolling join. Either way, there is an issue when its an exact match versus a time just after the `i.posix_dt` that needs to be handled.

Comment: If the first part is inefficient then maybe non-equi by=.EACHI join can be used there? sentiment and score could be merged into single line, then `frollmean` will compute them in parallel, `frollmean(list(sentiment, score), obs_back)`. Then you probably need to tweak `diag` as well.